# Integer dividing columns - SQLite

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

How is it possible to divide 2 columns and update with the result a third one?

```
UPDATE Table
SET success = (number_won_games / number_all_games)*100
WHERE name_game = 'some name'
```

This code is not updating my column, so I thought somebody of you guys could help me?

Comment: What's the schema of Table? What's some example data stored in it?

Comment: And what is success being set to with this update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue may be that **number_won_games** and **number_all_games** are integers and thus that the division will always be be 0 and thus 0 multiplied by 100 will then be 0, perhaps  giving the impression that nothing is updated.

You could try casting **number_won_games** and **number_all_games** to REAL e.g. using :-

```
UPDATE Table 
SET success = (CAST(number_won_games AS REAL) / CAST(number_all_games AS REAL)) * 100
WHERE name_game = 'some name';
```

---

### Explanatory Example

Considering the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t (name_game TEXT, number_won_games INTEGER, number_all_games INTEGER, success REAL);
INSERT INTO t VALUES
    ('game1',10,20,0.12345678);
UPDATE t SET success = (number_won_games / number_all_games) * 100;
SELECT * FROM t;
UPDATE t SET success = (CAST(number_won_games AS REAL) / CAST(number_all_games AS REAL)) * 100;
SELECT * FROM t;
```

- WHERE clause not needed, so has not been included.

Which inserts a row with 20 games played with 10 won (thus 50 as the success rate) and with success set to a non-zero value (to show that the first update does update) then

The first UPDATE as per your example result in :-

[image]

Whilst the second UPDATE, which casts the values to REAL results in :-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I feel like a trigger is your best bet here.  I don't have access to a database at the moment, but something like this would probably work.

```
CREATE TABLE counter(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, success REAL, number_won_games REAL, number_all_games REAL);

CREATE TRIGGER counter_update_success AFTER UPDATE ON counter
BEGIN
    UPDATE counter set NEW.success=((NEW.number_won_games/NEW.number_all_games)*100.0);
END;

CREATE TRIGGER counter_create_success AFTER INSERT ON counter
BEGIN
    UPDATE counter set NEW.success=((NEW.number_won_games/NEW.number_all_games)*100.0);
END;
```