# How do I divide integers in a GRDB SQLite filter?

Tags: swift, sqlite, grdb

I'm running a query in [GRDB](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift) in my Swift iOS app that tries to find vocab words that have been guessed incorrectly more than a specific %:

```swift
func getIncorrectWords(db: GRDB.Database, threshold: Double) throws -> [Word] {
  return words
    .filter(Column("timesCorrect") / Column("timesSeen") < threshold)
    .fetchAll(db);
}
```

But it's including all words that have *ever* been guessed wrong.

How can I get it to compare to the correct threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns are integers, so you're doing integer division.

In the SQLite, you have to [cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334818/788168) (`CAST(timesCorrect AS REAL) / timesSeen`), and there doesn't seem to be an alias in GRDB, so just write the SQL directly:

```swift
func getIncorrectWords(db: GRDB.Database, threshold: Double) throws -> [Word] {
  return words
    .filter(sql: "CAST(timesCorrect AS REAL) / timesShown < ?", arguments: [threshold])
    .fetchAll(db);
}
```